# How to define findOneBy($criteria) function?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

> I am very new to Symfony2, designing a simple login system. The userclass, 
>   router, controlerclass everything is working fine. I am stuck to 
>   userRepository class.
>
> My controller part is:

```
public function loginProcessAction(Request $request){

    if($request->getMethod() == "POST") {

        $username = $request->get('username');

        $password = $request->get('password');

        $em= $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $repository = $em->getRepository("LoginLoginBundle:Student");

        $user = $repository->findOneBy(array('username'=>$username,
                'password'=>$password));

        if($user){
            return $this->render('loginSuccess twig page') ;
        }
        else{
            return $this->render('error twig page') ;
        }


    } else{
        return $this->render("login error page");
    }
}

 How to define findOneBy(username, password) function in reopository class.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the best way to handle authentication when using Symfony2. Take a look at [the Security component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html) integrated with Symfony2.

So check [How Security Works: Authentication and Authorization](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#how-security-works-authentication-and-authorization) part of the [security documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html), all you need to implement/configure is [Firewalls](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#firewalls-authentication) to handle Authentication and 
[Access Controls](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#access-controls-authorization) for Authorization.

**But ...**

Here's an answer to the **common** question: How to a define findOneBy(parameter1, parameter2) function for a given repository class?

First, map your entity to the appropriate repository as follow,

```
/*
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="YourNamespace\YourBundle\Entity\yourRepository")
 */
class YourEntity
{
    // ...
}
```

You should then add the mapped repository class and implement a `findOneBy(parameter1, parameter2)` method.

You can then access this class within your controller as follow,

```
    $em= $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $yourEntityInstance = $em->getRepository("yourNamespaceYourBundle:YourEntity")
               ->findOneBy($parameter1, $parameter2);
```

Comment: And how to define findOneBy($parameter1, $parameter2) function in repository class.

Comment: There's already a native findOneBy() method you can use, so I don't really understand the need of rewrite it. Unless you need to change the way it behaves?